# Where to ask for beta testers (US) for a mobile banking app?

Tags: ios, mobile, banking, beta-testing, onlinebanking

I work for a company that creates a mobile banking application for iOS. We are now looking for beta testers in the US with Bank of America accounts or AMEX credit cards as beta tester; we are aware that this is a sensitive subject. Our companies core belief is that sensitive data belongs on the users device in an encrypted fashion only, and must only be used between the users device and the bank. Thus we strongly disagree with the idea of using a proxy server as broker between the users device and the bank. We are now looking for beta tester of our app. This brings me to this question: where should we ask for beta testers for our mobile banking app?

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation some months ago. The solution was: the bank's own employees tested the app. We had some testing accounts, from the bank as well, so we could test ourself (us devs, plus a tester). Only three accounts were allowed for testing. In this sensitive environments, I would stick with people that are part of the project and can in fact work in real conditions (project manager, product owners, or project's stockholders , from the bank side).

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Sadly, this is not an option for us. Are there any online forums about mobile banking? A google search didn't turn up anything. What would be terms someone in the US would look for?

Comment: Again I highly advise against looking for random people to test things that evolve money.

Comment: Thank you for strengthening your point; we are confident we are at the point though, where we can engage random people.

Answer (score 1):

1. If possible, mock the API first and test against mocked API first, not with real data.
2. If possible, get a copy of the production environment and test on it before testing on production.
3. Make sure you have somebody testing the application for security. If very sensitive data is  stored on the device, make sure nobody can get the information from a stolen device (jailbreak attack, data is encrypted, encryption keys/password not floating in memory etc, man-in-the-middle attacks between the app and the server, no sensitive data in logs, etc.)
4. Beta-testers, by definition, should be real users. You can pick them anywhere. However, make sure you have done everything you could before giving the application to them. Especially, make sure the users can't see/modify data of another users. Make sure you, as the developer company, can't see their data. Make sure you can block their access to the app anytime.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We've done 1., 2. and 3. already. The product is basically a derived version of an application we have been offering in the German market for a few years successfully.

Now we are at 4. The question was targeting at precisely that point, /where/ to pick beta tester.